# Remove settings.py tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[settings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings.py) should be dropped and its content merged with [django-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-settings).

Answer (score 10):

There's only 23 posts tagged with `settings.py`; we can retag these by hand. You start on one end, I'll start on the other and we'll meet in the middle.

.... aaand .... *Done*.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Ack, let's do that.

Comment: @Anto: That tooks us all of 3 minutes. :-)

Comment: http://media1.giphy.com/media/x28cIQSn19Tbi/giphy.gif

Comment: @Bart: Like that, but with fire-breathing Trogdors instead.

Comment: Yup !  I had no idea it was a common practice on SO to deal with that manually :o

Comment: Also: exact same issue with [tag:urls.py].  There are actually lots of `django-*` tags, I don't know if it's normal.

Comment: @Anto: I'd prefer dedicated `django-` tags for that. You could create a post for a larger undertaking where you identify tags like that for renaming, and we can all chip in.

Comment: It'd clearly be neater: ok, I'll do that.  Not fully familiar with Meta practices, sorry :)