# Django related tags reorganisation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Following up [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251685/1030960), it appears that a lot of tags are bubbling around [the Django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/).  While some of them clearly deserve to be merged or renamed ([settings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings.py) -> [django-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-settings), [urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urls.py) -> [django-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-urls)), there might be [some others](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185073/django-related-tags-on-stackoverflow) (191, not including tags that don't mention *django* but refer to it, like those mentioned above) to clean up.

**What's been done so far**

- [settings.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings.py) burninated
- [urls.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urls.py) burninated
- [url-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-tag) burninated
- [django-inline-formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-inline-formset) burninated
- [django-staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-staticfiles) is no longer a synonym of [static-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-files)

**What's next (proposals)**

- [django-multi-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-multi-db) to be merged with [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm)
- [django-many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-many-to-many) to be merged with [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm)
- [django-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-fields) to be merged with [django-models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-models)
- [django-imagefield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-imagefield) to be merged with [django-models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-models)
- [django-modelformsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-modelformsets) to be merged with [django-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-forms)
- [django-modelform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-modelform) to be merged with [django-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-forms)
- [django-generic-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-generic-views) to be merged with [django-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-views)
- [django-class-based-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-class-based-views) to be merged with [django-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-views)
- [django-modeladmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-modeladmin) to be merged with [django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-admin)
- [django-template-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-template-filters) to be merged with [django-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-templates)
- [django-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-queries) and [queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryset) to be merged with [django-queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-queryset) ([related meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280802/359284))
- burninate [django-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-messages)

Comment: I've started on `urls.py` already; I see there is a [proposed synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/django-urls/synonyms) already in place.

Comment: There may be one or two *non-Django* posts out there using `urls.py`; For [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965460/catch-all-routing-using-tipfy) I used `url-routing` instead.

Comment: Candidate burnination tag: [`url-tag`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/url-tag); a Django template tag. 6 questions tagged, it is rather useless.

Comment: 'the hell ?  I'm getting html code when I edit the question...

Comment: It is a [script gone haywire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230288/community-bot-doesnt-like-markdown); it'll be reverted, but you can do so yourself too. I've done so now.

Answer (score 7):

`urls.py` *and* `url-tag` have been

[image: tag burninated]

Keep 'em coming! I haven't (yet) seen any other obvious Django-isms in tags to rename / burninate.

Comment: Sorry, got quite busy today, I'll continue looking at it tomorrow :)  Nice work anyway !

Answer (score 3):

Some propositions:

- [django-formwizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-formwizard) to [django-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-forms)
- [django-admin-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-admin-filters) to [django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-admin)
- [django-related-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-related-manager) to [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm)
- [django-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-filter) and [django-template-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-template-filters) to [django-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-templates)

I think some tags (with 1 or 2 questions) should also be removed... The Django framework is huge, but it shouldn't have 191 different tags... We should focus tags (and merge other that may be related to these) around [django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-admin), [django-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-forms), [django-models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-models), [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm), [django-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-templates) if possible (even if models and orm are related...).

---

**Update 06/06**: I have killed some low tags (with 3 or 4 posts) to clean up a little bit... Most of the work is definitely on the one list above and in the original question, if someone has time/tools.

Comment: There are clearly way too many tags for Django.  One of the issues is that users tend to create a new tag for each Django app...  I don't know how this should be handled.  Some might think it's time to create a request on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just a heads up [tag:django-filter] is for the [django-filter app](https://github.com/alex/django-filter), not for the Django template tags filters.

Comment: @KevinBrown exactly! `django-filter` is for 3rd party app.

Comment: `django-formwizard` is about the 3rd party app ["form tools"](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io). Otherwise I agree that there should be only one tag for `django-admin`, only one tag for `django-orm`, same for `django-templates`. No further splitting! I don't see how does it help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are tags:

- `django-filter` and `django-filters`

The names are very confusing. The first one is about the 3rd party app [`django-filter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io).

The second one has no usage guidance and there is a link pointing to the documentation of an old Django version (1.9). It is pointing to the method `filter` in the chapter *"**QuerySet** API reference"*.

There is however already a tag `django-queryset`. The tag `django-filters` should be removed and all questions should go to `django-queryset`.

Further question is if we really need two different tags `django-queryset` and `django-orm`.

There are definitely way too many tags for `django`. I'd like to see many of them removed, merged, cleaned.

Another example is:

- `django-forms` and `django-formset`

where the later is not anymore used, but appears in the tag search results.

Also why it is needed to have:

- `django-views` and `django-generic-views`?

I don't see how does it help if we create tags for every class and method provided by Django.

In my opinion there should be:

- a main tag for `django` (as it is now)
- tags for specific Django versions, in standardized pattern, for example `django-1.9` (as it is now)
- tags for 3rd party Django apps, for example `django-celery` (as it is now)
- only few tags for bigger parts of the Django biotop, like `geodjango`, `django-models`, `django-forms`, `django-views`, `django-templates`, etc. (to be done)