# Make [django-queryset] the central tag for Django querysets

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Following up on [other Django-related meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251688/359284), I've noticed that Django has quite a few duplicate tags sitting around.

There are quite a few tags being used for [Django queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/)-related questions at the moment. It would make sense for all of these questions to be housed under the [django-queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-queryset) tag (which already exists), instead of having them spread out across multiple other tags.

A quick look through the [Django tags list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185073/django-related-tags-on-stackoverflow) shows these possible synonyms

- [django-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-queries) - 160 questions
- [queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryset) - 319 questions
- <del>[django-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-query) - 90 questions</del> (already retagged)